# AngualrJS "X" not restoring results after clearing text filter in IE

Tags: angularjs

I have a very simple text filter as follows within my AngularJS App. It filters the results, and the filtering works except if I hit the "X" for clearing results in Internet Explorer, it doesn't reset to show all results.

Here is the filter:

```
<div>
Filter Reports: <input type="text" data-ng-model="searchText" />
</div>
<tr ng-repeat="report in reportdata = (reports | filter:searchText)">
```

I noticed that this fiddle works to clear the values and restore the results: http://jsfiddle.net/joshkurz/Nk8qy/3/

Any clues/ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In looking at the needs. I decided to remove this with a little bit of CSS, as this will be more inline with cross browsers/mobile:

```
.textFilter::-ms-clear {
display: none;
}

<input class="textFilter" type="text" data-ng-model="searchText" />
```